# Insert into the same table without creating duplicates or NULLS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert-into

For SQL Server 2017, I have created a table called challenger

```
drop table if exists challenger
create table challenger (O_Ring_Failure char(1),
Launch_temperature float,
Leak_check_pressure char(10))
select * from challenger
insert into challenger values ('N',66,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',69,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',68,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',67,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',72,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',73,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',70,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('N',78,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',67,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',67,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',75,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',70,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',81,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',76,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',79,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',75,'High')
insert into challenger values ('N',76,'High')
insert into challenger values ('Y',70,'Low')
insert into challenger values ('Y',57,'High')
insert into challenger values ('Y',63,'High')
insert into challenger values ('Y',70,'High')
insert into challenger values ('Y',53,'High')
insert into challenger values ('Y',58,'High')
```

I want to extract from the *Launch_temperature* column by O_Ring_Failure to create two more columns Y_temperature and N_temperature(i.e., temperature for those O_Ring_Failure='Y' and 'N')

What I have written is the following:

```
alter table challenger add 
    Y_temperature float,
    N_temperature float;
go

with cte1
as
( select Launch_temperature  as y_temp from challenger where O_Ring_Failure='Y'),
cte2 as(select Launch_temperature  as n_temp from challenger where O_Ring_Failure='N')

insert into challenger 
    select y_temp， n_temp from cte1, cte2;
go
select * from challenger
```

Yet the results let me down:
[image: There are many NULLs in the beginning]

[image]

I want to pass this table and two columns to a stored procedure I have crated to calculate Z-score, so I don't need these NULLS in the beginning and duplicates for Y_temperature or N_temperature. Is there any way to get rid of them?

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
create procedure usp_bivariate
    @tbl varchar(200),
    @target_colname varchar(100),
    @predictor_colname varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    set @sql='with cte1(mean1,mean2, var1, var2, count1, count2) as ( select avg('+@target_colname+') as mean1, var('+@target_colname
    +') as var1,count('+@target_colname+') as count1, avg('+@predictor_colname+') as mean2, var('+@predictor_colname
    +') as var2,count('+@predictor_colname+') as count2 from '+@tbl+') select (mean1-mean2)/sqrt(var1/count1+var2/count2) from cte1' 
    exec(@sql)
end
```

Comment: Please do not use old-style joins, and are you looking for `UNION ALL`? Your question is not clear, what is the expected results? what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Considering that you added new columns and didn't run an `UPDATE` statement, what *were* you expecting to happen apart from the "old" rows to have the value `NULL`for the new columns? And for the new rows you inserted, why are you expecting the "old" columns to have a value when they weren't part of the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Sami I want to "just" bluntly insert things to specific columns regardless other values in a same row. Since after this I can feed column names and table name into my analytical procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want *counts* of each temperature?

```
select launch_temperature,
       sum(case when O_Ring_Failure = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as num_notfailures,
       sum(case when O_Ring_Failure = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as num_failures
from challenger
group by launch_temperature;
```

I can't think of anything else useful that would in any way fit your analytic goal.

Comment: My analytical procedural can do counts, averages, etc. I just want to select two series of temperature   by "Y' or  'N" and put them in two columns in the same table. Trailing NULLs are acceptable, but duplicates will affect later procedure.